# Bootstrap custom CSS rule how to set text-decoration:none for hyperlink?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

i am using twitter bootstrap css , and using some custom css to override few default rules. ,

but i am unable to remove the bottom border from a hyperlink ,

HTML

```
<footer>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 footer">   
<nav>
<a href="" >first link</a>
<a href="" class="nounderline">second link</a>  
<a href="" class="nounderline"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>     fb icon  </a> 
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");


.footer a{
color: #000;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
} 

.nounderline { text-decoration: none !important}
```

even though i have set class to `.nounderline`  its still showing the underline on hyperlink.

i have tried inline specifying  `text-decoration: none !important`

e.g. HTML

```
<a href="" class="nounderline" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i>     fb icon  </a>
```

but still its showing the underline for the hyperlink.

how can i remove the underline from the hyperlink ?

http://jsfiddle.net/x4eetcve/

Comment: remove `border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;` from `.footer a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `text-decoration` in this case. There's a dotted border line on `a` element.

```
.footer a {
   color: #000;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; 
}
```

Get rid of the border-bottom, then it will look okay.

I've updated your fiddle, check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/x4eetcve/1/

---

**Warning**

If you're using the `footer a` globally throughout pages like `Bootstrap` expects users to do, then you should override border-bottom on your `a.underline`.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't text-decoration, it is a bottom border. So use a slightly more specific selector and set border-bottom to none for your nounderline class.

example:

```
a.nounderline {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: that could be a comment, not answer

Comment: not sure what you mean by that, it's not a comment and was posted at the same time as the other answer.